# CSS works fine with url, does not work with local one

Tags: css

I have this strange problem that when I put the link of this .css file into the head of my html, the page works fine and gets the styles from that online .css file. But when I copy the entire content of that .css file and save it in my resources, it does not get the styles and does not work.
Does anybody has a solution for this strange behaviour?

this one works fine:

> < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/global.css" >

this one no:

> < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/global.css" >

this is another css file which I included and works fine with the same path directory:

> < link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/scrolling.css" type="text/css" >

Comment: does `resources/css/global.css` actually exist? These problems usually happen because you have the wrong path specified. Check the browser developer tools and see if the CSS file is actually being loaded, or if it throws a 404

Comment: yes, it exists and is located correctly @JacobGray

Comment: drag global.css into href from solution explorer. It will update properly..

Comment: could you please post the folder structure too..

Comment: So that means the files are located at `http://locahost/whateverdirectoryYou areAt/resources/css/global.css`

Comment: the problem is not the address, cuz I have also other css files and they work fine with the same directory path

Comment: Please post your entire tree structure

Comment: styles. It should fade background image when a video pops up, but it doesn't while using local .css, and works fine with the exact same online .css file

Comment: if you update your question with the entire file/folder structure and the background-image path I can tell whats wrong ... now everybody is just throwing guess answers

Comment: No, it is not. I want the entire folder/file structure and the background-image's url set in the css ... without it,  it's impossible to give a good answer ... and all existing answers prove my point, they just guess and none work

Comment: Thanks to all for your efforts. finally I found out that in that .css url file, there was a local addresses to it's repository, when I used the url it worked fine because it got the elements from local repository, but when I copied to my local, those local elements couldn't be found and that's why it did not work.
Resolved

Answer (score 1):

you must be sure of the correct location of the css file
is the location is correct try to add / before the href
like this:

```
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/global.css" >
```

same times if the location out of the folder you must be add two point like this

```
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/global.css" >
```

**i suggest you to be sure first if the location of css file is correct**

Comment: if you say there are multiple css file works fine must be sure if the name of this file is correct, maybe "globale.css" or somthing like this

Comment: the name is correct and autocompleted, but still not working, It's really strange, I don't know why??

Comment: so now go to the source page and top on head click on the url of this file and be sure if the css file load fine on your url browser

Answer (score 1):

I guess your structure is something like this:

```
- main-folder
  - resources
    - css
      global.css
  index.html
```

So if you wanna refrence `global.css` from `index.html`, it's better to write your `link` tag like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/css/global.css">
```

I mean by putting `./` at starting of `href`, you're telling the browser that ***file is located in here (dot), after that, go to resources and finally in the css folder there is a global.css file ***

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it was another issue which referred to a local element on that url which did not exist on mine. I resolved it

Answer (score 0):

Add a `/` in front of your path. When you have no slash at the beginning of the path, it inherits the path of the URL, and appends the path of the file. Adding the slash makes it "absolute"

You want it to be:

```
/resources/css/global.css
```

The path should be based from your root directory.

Comment: Without the slash is *also* an absolute path.  The initial slash makes it absolute *from the site root.*

Comment: What is your path to home directory?

Comment: When you try to access the fine directly in the browser, what is the error you receive?

Comment: this is not the only style .css file. there are others as well, and they work fine with this address, and the problem is not / for sure

Comment: Did you check the permissions?

Comment: @Ahop I dont get an error, this .css file contains fading background when a video pops up. and it does not fade background when I use local .css file

Comment: Try and open the file in the browser just to see if the resource is loading.

Comment: @reshad Hold on, is the CSS that isn't loading being linked from an HTML that is, itself, referenced/loaded inside *another HTML page?*  If that is the case, the path must be relative to the **parent page** not the popup.

Comment: @Draco18s how is it possible that without any change it works fine online, but not locally. this is the problem. I don't change any path

Comment: @reshad You need to better describe what you are doing, then.

Comment: Agreed, and check the permissions.